# Imperatively trigger an asynchronous request with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having trouble deciding how to trigger an API call *imperatively*, for example, on a button click.
I'm unsure what is the proper approach with hooks, because there seems to be more than one method, but I don't understand which is the "best" approach and the eventual implications.

I've found the following examples that are simple enough and do what I want:

#### Using useEffect() with a trigger value

```js
function SomeFunctionComponent() {
  const [fakeData, setFakeData] = useState(0);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

  async function fetchData() {
    if (!trigger) return;

    const newData = await someAPI.fetch();

    setTrigger(false);
    setFakeData(newData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [trigger]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{fakeData}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setTrigger(!trigger)}>Refresh</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv4261o9j3)

#### Just calling the API and then setState()

```js
function SomeFunctionComponent() {
  const [fakeData, setFakeData] = useState(0);

  async function fetchData() {
    const newData = await someAPI.fetch();

    setFakeData(newData);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{fakeData}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Refresh</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooqx35r6z9)

There are also other approaches that leverage useCallback() but as far as I understood they are useful to avoid re-rendering child components when passing callbacks down and are equivalent to the second example.

I think that the useEffect approach is useful only when something has to run on component mount *and* programmatically, but having what essentially is a dummy value to trigger a side-effect looks verbose.
Just calling the function looks pragmatic and simple enough but I'm not sure if a function component is allowed to perform side-effects during render.

Which approach is the most idiomatic and correct to have imperative calls using hooks in React ?

Comment: If you only want to run an effect when a button is clicked, it feels wasteful to introduce a piece of state just to make your effect run. It makes sense to use an effect if you e.g. want to fetch the data again if a prop changes, but in this case you might as well but the fetch in the event handler.

Comment: If you want it to load on mount as well (2nd option), just call your `fetchData` function inside a `useEffect` with `[]` to ensure only running once. This gives you the best of both worlds without the extra state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing I do when I try to figure out the best way to write something is to look at how I would like to use it. In your case this code:

```
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{fakeData}</p>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Refresh</button>
    </React.Fragment>
```

seems the most straightforward and simple. Something like `<button onClick={() => setTrigger(!trigger)}>Refresh</button>` hides your intention with details of the implementation.

As to your question remark that "I'm not sure if a function component is allowed to perform side-effects during render." , the function component isn't doing side-effects during render, since when you click on the button a render does not occur. Only when you call `setFakeData` does a render actually happen. There is no practical difference between implementation 1 and implementation 2 in this regard since in both only when you call `setFakeData` does a render occur.

When you start generalizing this further you'll probably want to change this implementation all together to something even more generic, something like:

```js
  function useApi(action,initial){
    const [data,setData] = useState({
      value:initial,
      loading:false
    });

    async function doLoad(...args){
        setData({
           value:data.value,
           loading:true
        });
        const res = await action(...args);
        setData({
            value:res,
            loading:false
        })
    }
    return [data.value,doLoad,data.loading]
  }
  function SomeFunctionComponent() {
    const [data,doLoad,loading] = useApi(someAPI.fetch,0)
    return <React.Fragment>
      <p>{data}</p>
      <button onClick={doLoad}>Refresh</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  }
```

Comment: I guess that, as always, simple and straight forward things are the best

Comment: I thought all side effects in function components must be performed inside a useEffect? Why is that not the case here? Thank you.

Comment: It's not a side effect. It's a user generated action in onClick

Comment: @AlonBarDavid a user generated action is _literally_ a side effect right? If the `SomeFunctionComponent` is destroyed before `setData()` is called, then it will throw an error

Comment: The fact that an error would occur if we used setData after the component is destroyed is true for every implementation provided. It's not really about side-effect or not, you have to affect the component state at some point to rerender the new data. To guard against it the correct way is to cancel the api request when the component is destroyed using useEffect's return call. It's rarely done though outside of library code, because it requires alot of boilerplate and we usually can assume it won't happen or we don't care if there's a warning if it does happen.

Comment: In regards to user generated action being a side effect. A side effect means that the function call (in this case the render call, since in functional components they are the same) causes an external service to act or changes the state of an external service, instead of returning the result.
Returning the onLoad function in the jsx isn't a side-effect. A side effect would be calling the onLoad function on first render for example. Since the render causes a change in an external service/state.

When the user clicks the button and onLoad is called- setData is a side effect in onLoad

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer does actually break the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). As the click is *Asynchronous*, which means other renders might occur during the fetch call which would create *SideEffects* and possibly the dreaded *[Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)*.

We can fix it by checking if the component is *mounted* before calling `setState()` functions. Below is my solution, which is fairly easy to use.

**Hook function**

```js
function useApi(actionAsync, initialResult) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(initialResult);
  const [fetchFlag, setFetchFlag] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchFlag == 0) {
      // Run only after triggerFetch is called 
      return;
    }
    let mounted = true;
    setLoading(true);
    actionAsync().then(res => {
      if (mounted) {
        // Only modify state if component is still mounted
        setLoading(false);
        setResult(res);
      }
    })
    // Signal that compnoent has been 'cleaned up'
    return () => mounted = false;
  }, [fetchFlag])

  function triggerFetch() {
    // Set fetchFlag to indirectly trigger the useEffect above
    setFetchFlag(Math.random());
  }
  return [result, triggerFetch, loading];
}
```

**Usage in React Hooks**

```js
function MyComponent() {
  async function fetchUsers() {
    const data = await fetch("myapi").then((r) => r.json());
    return data;
  }

  const [fetchResult, fetchTrigger, fetchLoading] = useApi(fetchUsers, null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchTrigger}>Refresh Users</button>
      <p>{fetchLoading ? "Is Loading" : "Done"}</p>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(fetchResult)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```